# Natively looking checkboxes in SWT/Jface tables

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, swt, jface

Are there any tested solutions that enables me to have natively looking checkboxes in SWT tabes?

After long googling i found clever way to [create image screenshoots of SWT checkbox buttons](http://www.playingwithwire.com/2007/12/swt-jface-tableviewer-checkbox/), but it has some weird bugs.

Anyone has a tested real-life solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog entry you quote might be superseded by this [JFace Snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet061FakedNativeCellEditor.java?view=markup). Haven't tried that though.

But I'd simply place the checkboxes into the `Table` on your own [like this](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet126.java?view=co)? Powerful and native. I did use this in a real life solution. For huge tables (thousands of entries) you'll run out of handles, though. (Maybe using `SWT.VIRTUAL` would help, then.)

Comment: I'll check that out. As to the using checkboxes I wasn't aware you can (I' mostly a swing guy, and most of the tutorials used Viewers and some kinds of images that would replace checkboxes). 

Number of rows is not a problem :)